# Sed not replacing new line pattern in text file

Tags: bash, sed, grep, wc, findandmodify

I've got a `txt` file that I've retrieved from SQL Server Manager and hence the line delimitor is `'\r\n'`. I would like to change this line delimitor to `'\n'`. You can see my approach below. The problem is that even afer running the sed, it looks like `'\r\n'` was not replaced, as you can see below. What am I missing out here?

```
>>> grep \r\n some_file.txt |wc -l
21321

>>>sed -i 's/\r\n/\n/g' some_file.txt
>>> grep \r\n some_file.txt |wc -l
21321
```

I am using:

```
sed (GNU sed) 4.4
```

on Linux 4.15 Ubuntu

Comment: Just use `sed -i 's/\r//g' some_file.txt` as sed operates on a per line basis.

Comment: To give a little insight: `sed` removes the standard `\n` line termination from your file input during script execution and re-appends it on output. In between, it only holds `…\r` in its pattern space, which is why you can never match `\r\n` at the end of a line – there is no `\n`. You need to match for a single `\r` at the end of line and replace that with an empty string.

Comment: to extend Robin479's comment, you can match the end of the line with the `$` char, so `\r$` . Good luck.

Comment: @shellter still not working

Comment: @Robin479 it did that too, but still dos not work

Comment: Come to think of it, I don't think `sed` honnors `\r`, `\n` sort of "notation", you'll need to specify the Ctrl Char version, and because of various historical contstraints, `\r=^M`, while `\n=^J`. If you're using a `vi` based cmd-line editor, you need to escape those chars with a `^V`, so, I think you really want `sed 's/^V^M$//' file` (note the `g` is not needed). And that means hold down Ctrl key, press `v`, keep Ctrl key down, press `m`. You won't see the `^V` appear on the cmd-line. .....

Comment: And, of course, assuming that you are only looking to convert a `DOS` file to `UNIX` format, your system may have the utility built just for this purpose, `dos2unx file [files....n]` . OR if you're on a primitive system, hopefully you can do `tr -d '\013' file > file.tmp && mv file.tmp file`. If none of this helps, please provide the output of `uname -srv` and `sed --version`. In fact as a newbie, it would be a good idea to make that the first information in all questions you post. Good luck!

Comment: @shellter thanks. it turns out I do not have dos2unx. In the same time sed 's/^V^M$//' did not do it and the tr gives me a syntax error

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo that I missed, `dos2unix file [file(s).....]` . OR please paste exact error message from `tr`. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter, got it, however I don't have it.I did howerver mention my linux and sed version

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
sed -i 's/\r//' some_file.txt
```

Comment: did it, however the grep still shows just as many cases, so it still did not work